# webpack not load js files in in Chrome Dev tools

Tags: vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, nuxt3

I have nuxt 3 with webpack and vue 3

When i want to check error in console and click on  file(on the right) i got this:
Could not load content for webpack://nuxt-app/?31d6 (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

How error looks in console:
[image]

That is, the problem is that I don’t have code in some files and I can’t see where the error is

But some files are displayed well

Tried different browsers, same thing.

Nuxt config:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
builder: 'webpack',


hooks: {

    webpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader'
                },
                // Дополнительные правила для обработки стилей и скриптов, если необходимо
            ],
            plugins: [
                // Добавьте плагин VueLoaderPlugin
                new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                new VuetifyPlugin()
            ],

        },
        plugins: [
            // Добавьте плагин VueLoaderPlugin
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new VuetifyPlugin()
        ],

        config(configs) {
            // plugins: [
            //     new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            //     new VuetifyPlugin(),
            // ]


        }
    }

},

app: {

typescript: { shim: false },
build: {
    mode: 'production',
    transpile: ["vuetify"],
    devtool: 'source-map'

},
devtools: { enabled: true },

    modules: [

        '@nuxt/image'

    ],



 })
```

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there's no `auth` in code

Comment: yes i understand, but where i want to know)

Comment: Search your code base for `.auth` string. It's likely that the exact location will be shown if you press at the first entry in error call stack (eval...)